# UIImageView with gestures recognizers Xcode Ios

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview, gestures

I have a `UIImageView` with gestures recognizers (scale, rotate, translate).

But after using it, the gestures don't work.

And my `UIImageview` changes the size and position.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: And my uiimageview change the size and position. :S

Comment: You need to post some code to show what you're trying to do...

Comment: my code is very very large and not have idea in that part happens this  issue, thanks for help me

Comment: starting off with posting code for initializing and setting the UIImageView's frame would be good enough for now.... it would probably solve the issue itself or at least point in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

By default, UIImageViews do not have user interaction enabled.  Try setting your UIImageView's user interaction enabled to "YES":

```
[myImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: At start app, the first run very good, But after using it, the gestures don't work. and my image change values of the scale and position, i try the release but with this my app crash.
I remake the project.
Thanks.